# How to make low latency for HLS live streaming?

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have setup the live-stream with **Flash Media Live Encoder 3.2**, **adobe media server 5.0**, and **VideoJS** for HTML5 Player. It is about 10-20 seconds delay after adjust the setting.

I have reading what Apple and Adobe mention about the delay 25 and 30 second? Is it possible to adjust the setting to **low latency** (About 2 second latency) or alternative solution for low latency Live Streaming that support mobile device?

[Apple Site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html) 
**Q 21. What is the latency?** 
Approximately 30 seconds, with recommended settings.

[Adobe Site](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/ams/pdfs/ams5-intro-wp.pdf) 
**HTTP Live Streaming for Apple iOS (HLS)** 
**Page 25:** Higher latency due to real-time fragmenting process (a minimum of 25 seconds should be expected).

Answer (score 3):

Use a `HLSMediaFileDuration` that is a multiple of the keyframe interval and lower the keyframe interval.

The player needs at least 3 segments to start the playback, so you can use segments of 1s length with keyframes each second.

This has disadvantages as it increases the stream size due to more frequent keyframes, adds a lot of overhead and requires more frequent playlist refreshes thus increasing the number of HTTP requests.

https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/dev/configure-dynamic-streaming-live-streaming.html